# Writing Spark-SQL queries involving Complex types

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark-SQL and trying to come to terms with it. We use `Spark-SQL` primarily for data transformations/manipulations for `ETL`. Recently, I have stumbled upon few `SparkSQL` functions for manipulating Spark Complex Types (`array`, `map`, `struct` etc). I came across certain functions such as `array()`, `array_zip()`, `struct()`, `map_concat()`, `map_from_arrays()` etc. I searched online but unfortunately, I could not get enough examples/explanations involving them for me to have a clear understanding.

Can anyone please provide some examples of its applications so that I can have a better understanding for me to be able to apply them in our project tasks.

Note: I only have access to `Spark-SQL` but **Not** `PySpark-SQL`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below explination,

**array** 
array(expr, ...) - Returns an array with the given elements.

Examples:

> SELECT array(1, 2, 3);
>   [1,2,3]

**arrays_zip** 
arrays_zip(a1, a2, ...) - Returns a merged array of structs in which the N-th struct contains all N-th values of input arrays.

Examples:

> SELECT arrays_zip(array(1, 2, 3), array(2, 3, 4));
>    [{"0":1,"1":2},{"0":2,"1":3},{"0":3,"1":4}]
>   SELECT arrays_zip(array(1, 2), array(2, 3), array(3, 4));
>    [{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3},{"0":2,"1":3,"2":4}]

**struct**

> struct(col1, col2, col3, ...) - Creates a struct with the given field values.

**map**
map(key0, value0, key1, value1, ...) - Creates a map with the given key/value pairs.

Examples:

> SELECT map(1.0, '2', 3.0, '4');
>    {1.0:"2",3.0:"4"}

**map_concat**
map_concat(map, ...) - Returns the union of all the given maps

Examples:

> SELECT map_concat(map(1, 'a', 2, 'b'), map(2, 'c', 3, 'd'));
>    {1:"a",2:"c",3:"d"}

**map_from_arrays**
map_from_arrays(keys, values) - Creates a map with a pair of the given key/value arrays. All elements in keys should not be null

Examples:

> SELECT map_from_arrays(array(1.0, 3.0), array('2', '4'));
>    {1.0:"2",3.0:"4"}

For more built in Spark functions, please go through below link, 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/